# Can dictionary keys be forced to a particular order?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.7

I know that normally the order of keys/values in a dictionary is arbitrary.  However, if you declare a dictionary "longhand" (see below) and then never add or remove any keys, does this mean that the key order will be kept as you declared it?

I've done a couple of brief experiments and the answer *seems* to be Yes, but before I count on this, I wanted to make sure.

When I say "longhand", I just mean an explicit declaration of each key & value all at a shot:

```
myDict = {key1: val1, key2: val2, key3: val3, .... }
```

Comment: While it is likely they will not change ordering, it is not guaranteed. Why would you need to rely on the order being constant?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thanks -- I missed that one when searching previous threads.

Comment: @bplattenburg, I'm setting up the framework behind a Tkinter GUI and was a considering a dictionary as a way to store the labels & values for a collection of radiobuttons.  There's more to the story of course on why I want to do *that*, but that's the answer to your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dictionaries are inherently unordered in Python. Use `collections.OrderedDict` if you want to preserve ordering. Note that `collections.OrderedDict` preserves *insertion order*.

Also, a counterexample to the notion that keys are kept in declaration order:

```
>>> {1:2, 4:5, 2:3}
{1: 2, 2: 3, 4: 5}
```

Dictionary keys also need not be sorted:

```
>>> {-1:-1, -2:-2, 1:1}
{1: 1, -2: -2, -1: -1}
```

So, don't ever rely on the order of a dictionary's keys unless you know it's an `OrderedDict`.